# How to display data from the Object of a ListView that is in a ListView in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm new to C# WPF and was trying to create a List within a List. I have a List of Person and each Person have a List of Friends. I was able to do this using ListView within a ListView. I am trying to create a Button for every friend and display the Name of the Friend through a MessageBox but I do not know how.

This is my ListView within a ListView

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding people}" x:Name="ListA">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TabItem Header="{Binding Name}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ListView x:Name="ListB" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" Margin="100,0,0,0">
                             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Show Name" Margin="0,0,0,100"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name }"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

This is my xaml.cs

```
public List<Person> people { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        people = new List<Person>();

        

        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.Name = "Mark";
        person1.Friends = new List<Friend>();
        person1.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend A"));
        person1.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend B"));
        person1.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend C"));

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.Name = "John";
        person2.Friends = new List<Friend>();
        person2.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend D"));
        person2.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend E"));
        person2.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend F"));

        Person person3 = new Person();
        person3.Name = "Peter";
        person3.Friends = new List<Friend>();
        person3.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend G"));
        person3.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend H"));
        person3.Friends.Add(new Friend("Friend I"));

        people.Add(person1);
        people.Add(person2);
        people.Add(person3);

        DataContext = this;

        
    }
```

I can access ListA in xaml.cs but not ListB and I do not know why. I may be wrong in approaching the problem but I dont really know anyway how.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps you but let's give it a try :) [WPF-ListViewItem Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713752/binding-a-list-of-object-to-a-wpf-listviewitem)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741898/wpf-button-click-event